# The window I created in C++ is not displayed

Tags: c++, winapi

I tried to create a window in an Empty C++ Project in Visual Studio, but when I run it, it shows me no window. However, it doesn't give me any error too.

```
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow ) 
{
    const auto pClassName = "TextClass";
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor = nullptr;
    wc.hbrBackground = nullptr;
    wc.lpszMenuName = pClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = nullptr;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        pClassName,
        "A sad Window",
        WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        200, 200, 640, 480,
        nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this really takes me back in time. Windows 3.1 programming... Instead of `while(true)` you need a message handling loop.

Comment: Your code doesn't check for errors. Does `RegtisterClass` succeed? Does `CreateWindowEx` succeed? If not then you need to [figure out the error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).

Comment: Check out the basic example: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html

Comment: Also check out, [Your first Windows program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program). Although you passed the windows class name as an argument to `CreateWindowEx`, you might also need to set `wc.lpszClassName`.

Comment: So many questions without error checking........ Do yourself a favour and learn to check for errors in Win32 code.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo: you are setting

```
 wc.lpszMenuName = pClassName;
```

instead of wc.lpszClassName.

I believe just fixing that will get the window on the screen but the executable will then hang with it on the screen because nothing is fielding messages.

A minimal message loop instead of

```
while (true) ...
```

would be

```
MSG msg;
while( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) > 0 )
    DispatchMessage( &msg );
```

Comment: besides, add the `UpdateWindow(hwnd);`, maybe `TranslateMessage(&Msg);` also needed. :)